# Unexpected Case In a Loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy1(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; (s1[i] = s2[i]) != '\0'; i++)
        ;
}

void copy2(char *s1, const char *s2) {    
    for ( ; (*s1 = *s2) != '\0'; s1++, s2++)
        ;
}

int main() {
    char string1[10]; 
    char *string2 = "Hello"; 
    char string3[10]; 
    char string4[] = "Good Bye";
    copy1(string1, string2);
    printf("string1 = %s\n", string1);
    copy2(string3, string4);
    printf("string3 = %s\n", string3);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code like this but I expected that it should print :

```
Hello56789
Good Bye89
```

But it produced just:

```
Hello Good Bye
```

I couldn't understand why this occurs.I thought like that the loop will stop when `string2` and `string4` reaches the '\0'. If this happens why can't I see the remaining numbers which is in the array (56789..) ?

I mean that Hello's length is 5.When  this happens : `for ( i = 0; ( s1[ i ] = s2[ i ] ) != '\0'; i++ )`Just after 5th element of Hello , \0 comes and loop is over.So,the elements of array which are 0,1,2,3,4 replaced by Hello's letters.Yet,there are still 5,6,7,8,9 in string1 which are not replaced.We print the string1 with %s can it be the reason why I couldn't see the numbers ?

Comment: @EdHeal No he isn't. The expression `( s1[ i ] = s2[ i ] ) != '\0'` first copies the NULL and only then evals to false.

Comment: Sorry - You are right

Comment: Where do you have remaining numbers in any of these arrays?

Comment: You code prints something totally different: `string1 = Hello` on the first line, `string3 = Good Bye` on the second line. Check if the output that you show us is indeed produced by your code.

Comment: Why the excepted output is fill by "56789" or "89"? You don't init `string1` and `string3` in your [mcve], fix your question please!

Comment: After latest edit: *What* makes you think that there are letters from 0 to 9 in your arrays? You haven't assigned them to the array. There is no automatic assignment of char array elements to letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual output I would expect is this:

```
string1 = Hello
string3 = Good Bye
```

Both functions implement the copy part of `strcpy()`, using index notation and pointer pushing respectively.  They both copy characters from the source (second argument) into the destination (first argument) upto and including the null terminator. Evaluating the test actually copies the character: the null terminator is copied and the loop stops.

The rest of the destination arrays `string1` and `string3` remains uninitialized. They do not contain anything precise: these arrays are allocated on automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) and are **not** initialized.  I don't know where you derive this notion of initial contents for arrays, maybe from some sample program that did initialize arrays with this contents, but no such thing happens by default.

`printf()` outputs the contents of the array `string1` as an argument for the `%s` format, deemed to be a C string, and stops when it reaches the null terminator.

Comment: Thank you , the last sentence solved the problem which is in my brain :D

Answer (score 0):

The loop exit condition is a null character (`\0`). This character is seen at the end of the string.

There is no source for the number characters to appear from, therefore they don't

Answer (score 0):

You have to init string1 and string3 with 0..9 before you use your copy functions, but before init you have to extend the field length of string1 and string3 from 10 to 11 (the \0 char is added):
`strcpy(string1,"0123456789");
    strcpy(string3,"0123456789");`

Comment: Even if the OP did that, the behavior of the program would be unchanged.

Comment: @chqrlie, yes, you are right, because in the copy functions the \0 of the source string is copied.

Comment: yes. Also copying `"0123456789"` to `string1` and `string3` causes buffer overflows as `strcpy` will also copy the null terminators beyond the end of the destination arrays.